# Getting data from database using ODBC connection

Tags: r, odbc

Getting the error 1655 when try to run the query to the database within R-Studio on Windows 11 machine
The same code on the old machine with Windows 10 works good

Since changing the computer (the old had Windows 10, the new with Windows 11) my ODBC query stopped work in the same code.
The connection to database establish without error:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

ImpODBC <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "********", uid = "******", PWD = "*******")
```

But the query

```
IMP_Sales <- dbGetQuery(ImpODBC, "Select SBLOC,SBCUST,SBSMNO,SBITEM,SBTYPE,SBINDT,SBPHYP,SBQSHP,SBEPRC,SBPRIC,SBICST,SBINV,SBCOSTPC,SBUM,SASHIP 
                             From R50FILES.VSADETL 
                             JOIN R50FILES.VSAHEAD 
                             ON SBCMP=SACMP and SBORD=SAORD and SABOCD=SBBOCD 
                             Where SBINV<>999999999 and SBPCOD <> 'LS' and SBCMP = 1 and SBPHYP between 202201 and 202212 and SBITEM <> ''")
```

returns the following error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: HY000: 躠娽ŋ 覀娽ŋ                
<SQL> 'Select SBLOC,SBCUST,SBSMNO,SBITEM,SBTYPE,SBINDT,SBPHYP,SBQSHP,SBEPRC,SBPRIC,SBICST,SBINV,SBCOSTPC,SBUM,SASHIP 
                             From R50FILES.VSADETL 
                             JOIN R50FILES.VSAHEAD 
                             ON SBCMP=SACMP and SBORD=SAORD and SABOCD=SBBOCD 
                             Where SBINV<>999999999 and SBPCOD <> 'LS' and SBCMP = 1 and SBPHYP between 202201 and 202212 and SBITEM <> '''
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The 5 Dec 2022 Windows patch broke ODBC connections.  There is no workaround and Microsoft is aware and working it, timeline unknown.  I'm using an unpatched computer for a critical database function in the meantime.

Comment: I coninue to investigate this issue and found out only one difference.
The new R-Studio has the following

> str(l10n_info())
List of 5
 $ MBCS           : logi TRUE
 $ UTF-8          : logi TRUE
 $ Latin-1        : logi FALSE
 $ codepage       : int 65001
 $ system.codepage: int 65001

but the old shows the following

> str(l10n_info())
List of 5
 $ MBCS           : logi FALSE
 $ UTF-8          : logi FALSE
 $ Latin-1        : logi TRUE
 $ codepage       : int 1252
 $ system.codepage: int 1252